# Using "interior" door lever on an exterior door

Tags: doors, lock

I'm replacing the doorknob on my front door; I like the look of [this lever](https://ca.weiserlock.com/en/products/halifax-square-rose-passage-levers-satin-nickel/9SPSL1010-012/), but it's described as

> ***For use on interior doors*** requiring no locking functionality, such as hallway or closet doors.

(emphasis mine)

I have a deadbolt, so don't feel the need to spend the extra $30 on [the locking variant](https://ca.weiserlock.com/en/products/halifax-square-rose-keyed-entry-levers-satin-nickel/9SENL5350-013/) which is described as

> For use on exterior doors where keyed entry and security is needed.

As far as I can tell the materials are the same and I should be okay using the non-locking lever. Obviously it depends on the product, but generally speaking is "for use on interior doors" just a recommendation based on security needs? Or is there some reason I should get the locking model?

Comment: I agree with others that I haven’t noticed any real difference in the operators (door knobs or lever handles) other than the the locking mechanism itself. The latch is usually the exact same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly that because I was always getting locked out. The finish on an exterior knob/handle may not last as long if used as an exterior knob/handle. I have a storm door with glass so that's not a concern for me. If someone is trying to break in they'll have a harder time with the deadbolt than the door knob.

Comment: First thing I did when moving into my house many years ago was have someone (I had no idea at the time...and no YouTube back then!) disable the locking mechanism of the bottom lock - useless for keeping anyone out except the owner (on a stormy day...).

Comment: I really haven’t noticed any difference in finish just different hardware++